# Eclipse Bug: Unhandled event loop exception No more handles

Tags: eclipse, swt

I've built a GUI using Swing and the MigLayout.

I am using Eclipse 4.2.2 (64-bit) on Windows 7 Ultimate.
Every time I click back into the window to edit my code, a popup comes up, then I'm prompted to restart Eclipse, and the Event log says the following:

```
 org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
    ...
```

I'm attaching screenshots of the error messages.
Has anyone else encountered this bug with Eclipse? Do you know of a work-around or a fix?

[image: 1. Problem Occurred Message]

[image: 2. Internal Error Message asking me to close Eclipse]

[image: 3. Event Details]

Comment: Exact same problem here. I wish someone would come with a better alternative than just downgrading...

Comment: Yea, it's irritating. I still haven't found a proper solution.

Comment: I have this problem persistent in one my pc, but it does not happen in another pc. It is quite annoying. I have to stuck with Eclipse 3.8 and ADT2.1

Comment: Here's a bug that seems related to this problem : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983 . It seems that having a dual monitor setup could be related ... Do you guys work on 2 monitors as I do ?

Comment: I have this problem and I'm on two monitors

Comment: Amazin. I have this error on a brand new computer with fresh install with such a versions of java and eclipse what I was using before without any such a problem.

Comment: I know this is an old topic but...for me I was able to delete the ".projects" directory in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/ directory and then everything worked fine. I did loose some local history...no biggie to me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a workaround: Change the Java editor to WindowBuilder.

*Eclipse → Windows → Preferences → File Associations →*, choose *WindowBuilder Editor* as Java default editor.

Comment: Full path is Eclipse / Windows / Preferences and then General / Editors / File Associations
And in my case there is no "WondowBuilder Editor" available as editor :(

Comment: nice one! you can actually download the window builder here http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201309271200/4.3/

Comment: I tried the same thing but the error still there.
I have installed the window builder and choose as default java editor.

Comment: It is working partially to me. I have installed and finally got not such an errors when switching to java editor. But I still got it when I have switched to (e.g.) variable view in debug perspective.

Comment: I did installed the windowBuilder plugin and it seemed it worked but after a while it started again

Comment: I added "Java Editor" under the "associated editors" and marked it as default and that worked.

Comment: Does not solved my problem.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem, turned out that TeamViewer was causing this.

In your TeamViewer go to:

*Extras → Options → Advanced → QuickConnect* button, configure it and disable the show *QuickConnect* button.

Comment: I can't see QuickConnect option in v13.0.6447

Answer (score 12):

As suggested by [Nineroad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2388416/nineroad) Installing WindowBuilder as the default editor for files with a *.java extention fixed this issue for me.

In Eclipse, navigate to ***Help > Install New Software***

Add **http://archive.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201309271200/4.3** to the "Work with" path, select all components suggested, and install WindowBuilder.

Once complete, Eclipse will request restart.
Once restarted, within Eclipse navigate to **Window > Preferences**.
In The Preferences dialogue-box navigate to **General > Editor > File Associations**.
Under "File Associations" list, be sure to select ***.java** file types. The bottom window (labeled "Associated Editors") should have *WindowBuilder* as an option. Select WindowBuilder and click "Default" to the right, to set WindowBuilder as your default *.java file editor.

This fixed the **SWT error** for me.

Note: *Eclipse
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Windows 7 64-bit*

Answer (score 6):

It is hardware problem at all.

If you have nView, turn off Desktop Manager. In case of ATI, turn off HydraVision.

This works fine on Eclipse Kepler (Standard) and Android Developer Tools Edition.

Comment: Sorry, i know it is a very old post to bump but Wow thank you so much! it really solved my problem! in my case it was AMD Catalyst controll center and i had to go to "Settings > Advanced View" and then to the left, "HydraVision > Manage Desktop > General Settings > Enable Desktop Management" and untick this. 

Note: The paths above are translated in english, the transation may not be accurate at all.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 6):

I had DisplayFusion running, which is a special Windows program used to manage multiple monitors. Turning it off seemed to fix this issue for me.

Comment: A commenter on [the Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983#c67) suggests that adding a compatibility entry for `eclipse.exe` and checking `Disable TitleBar Buttons (this application only)` as a less drastic solution.

Answer (score 4):

in short: check out if the bold sections below may save your day :-)

(This answer may help but the source problem is still not found. I'll update my findings if satisfyingly solved.)

*<updates...>*

*update:* It just happened again and occurred on dragging/positioning of one XML file (Tomcats content.xml) underneath all other files. (Opened by "XML Editor": Provider: `Eclipse Web Tools Platform`, Plug-in Name: `XML editor`, Version: `1.0.700.v201005192212`, Plug-in Id: `org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user`)

*update2:* On further looking into it the error disappears when I move the editor back to the other files (all open editors in one area). Furthermore it appears only when entering or leaving this XML editor, not on e.g. making changes to it and saving it via CRTL+S. Other than that the JBoss-related exception from below occurs on the CTRL+S event, but independent of this issue (so it may not be related at all).

*update3:* Getting even closer: since some time there has been a new editor positioning feature around. (Initially I was a bit confused, but now I am getting the point and even visually can see what is meant and what makes the difference...). 
So there are two ways to position editors vertically or horizontally next to other editors:

1. positioning it inside the same "panel" (indicated by a global and two inner panels/borders/rectangles around the editors) and
2. positing it next to the old "panel" (indicated by a rectangle frame around the old panel and the new one.

**So putting an editor in a new "global" panel (2.) works fine, putting it in a new "local" panel (1.) causes the issue**
(that's actually very helpful because I can still continue to work quite efficiently)
(maybe somebody else could report this bug appropriately)
(it also seems not related to the XML editor mentioned above since it also happens e.g. on property files)

*update 4:* I am using Windows 7 in hibernate mode. Meaning I don't start my Eclipse too often. Now I realized that **Eclipse itself had been started (looking at the Task Manager) 2 times** (visually and using ALT+TAB for open windows navigation this was not obvious).
After (stopping/killing all open instances and) restarting the problem does not occur anymore.

*update 5:* In this duplicate question somebody stated it would have been **solved by the latest windows update**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316804/1915920 . I'll check this out for myself, but currently I cannot reproduce the problem anyways.

*update 6:* In another situation I had this and it seemed related to some property window (in this case Jasper Reports) that updated its content automatically, based on the current editor (like an outline view). So it could be a good idea to **close and re-open (all) outline and/or property windows**.

*</...updates>*

The error in general indicates, that some program(s) have (propably) unusually many (probably thousands?) of operating system file handles open.
So one should check if outside or inside of Eclipse a lot of files are opened at the same time or opened over a short period of time, 
but not properly closed (they could be visually closed, but the operating system still thinks they are beeing used because
the application did not properly free the file handles somehow).

Now I have this issue currently as well. If I look in the Error Log (Window->Show View->General->Error Log) 
I can see a lot of the following org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.* exceptions immediately before.
Since I don't use the installed JBoss Developer Studio Plugin (that is likely related to this one) right now and 
no associated window or editor is opened (only some toolbar "JBoss Central" and perspective "JBoss" buttons) I'll have
a look if disabling these will help on this sporadic problem.
Also I closed all open editors, restarted Eclipse and open them and can't see this issue right now again.

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
```

...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener$2.visit(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:49)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener.resourceChanged(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2354)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.executeOperation(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.saveDocument(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.performSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:5068)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.tools.common.editor.ObjectMultiPageEditor.saveX(ObjectMultiPageEditor.java:403)
    at org.jboss.tools.common.editor.ObjectMultiPageEditor.doSave(ObjectMultiPageEditor.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$2.run(SaveableHelper.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$5.run(SaveableHelper.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1812)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1809)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.savePart(SaveableHelper.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveSaveable(WorkbenchPage.java:3777)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3790)
    at org.jboss.tools.common.model.ui.texteditors.SaveAction3.run(PropertiesTextEditorComponent.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1525)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4611)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4977)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

...

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
```

installed plugins (Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details->Installed Software: mark all + CTRL+C):
(Eclipse Kepler Java EE and BIRT edition as base install)

```
  Apache Directory Studio LDAP Browser  2.0.0.v20130628 org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.feature.feature.group   Apache Software Foundation
  DevUtilsFeature   1.0.9.201209201734  DevUtilsFeature.feature.group   null
  Eclipse IDE for Java and Report Developers    2.0.0.20130613-0530 epp.package.reporting   null
  GlassFish Tools   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group    Oracle
  JarPlug   0.6.1   com.simontuffs.eclipse.jarplug.feature.feature.group    simontuffs.com
  Jaspersoft Studio feature 5.2.0   com.jaspersoft.studio.feature.feature.group Jaspersoft Corporation
  Java EE 5 Documentation   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.javaee.doc.v5.feature.group    Oracle
  Java EE 6 Documentation   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.javaee.doc.v6.feature.group    Oracle
  Java EE 7 Documentation   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.javaee.doc.v7.feature.group    Oracle
  JBoss Developer Studio (Core Features)    7.0.0.GA-v20130720-0044-B364    com.jboss.jbds.product.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  Log Viewer Feature    0.9.8.8 de.anbos.eclipse.logviewer.feature.feature.group    Andre Bossert
  MercurialEclipse  2.1.0.201304290948  mercurialeclipse.feature.group  MercurialEclipse project
  MyLV  1.0.4   mylv_feature.feature.group  null
  Oracle ADF Documentation (11.1.1.4)   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.adf.doc.v11114.feature.group   Oracle
  Oracle ADF Documentation (11.1.1.5)   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.adf.doc.v11115.feature.group   Oracle
  Oracle ADF Documentation (11.1.1.6)   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.adf.doc.v11116.feature.group   Oracle
  Oracle ADF Documentation (11.1.1.7)   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.adf.doc.v11117.feature.group   Oracle
  Oracle ADF Documentation (12.1.2) 6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.adf.doc.v1212.feature.group    Oracle
  Oracle ADF Tools  6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.adf.feature.group  Oracle
  Oracle Cloud Tools    6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.cloud.feature.group    Oracle
  Oracle Coherence Tools    6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.coherence.feature.group    Oracle
  Oracle Database Tools 6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.database.feature.group Oracle
  Oracle Java EE Tools  6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.javaee.feature.group   Oracle
  Oracle Maven Tools    6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.maven.feature.group    Oracle
  Oracle Spring Tools   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.spring.feature.group   Oracle
  Oracle WebLogic Scripting Tools   6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.scripting.feature.group   Oracle
  Oracle WebLogic Server Tools  6.2.0.201307232054  oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.feature.group Oracle
  Toad® Extension for Eclipse - Community Edition - Core Plugin 1.8.3.201308140922  com.quest.toadext.core.feature.feature.group    Quest Software, Inc.
  Toad® Extension for Eclipse - Community Edition - MySQL DB Plugin 1.8.3.201308140922  com.quest.toadext.mysql.feature.feature.group   Quest Software, Inc.
  Toad® Extension for Eclipse - Community Edition - Oracle Database Plugin  1.8.3.201308140922  com.quest.toadext.feature.feature.group Quest Software, Inc.
  Toad® Extension for Eclipse - Community Edition - PostgreSQL Plugin   1.8.3.201308140922  com.quest.toadext.postgre.feature.feature.group Quest Software, Inc.
```

Comment: For me it still happens today (I just migrated to Keppler) when viewing the source of a class file (Ctrl + click on a method that takes you to the source of a compiled class). When viewing the source of that class file if I click on the debug view and then come back to the editor I systematically get this error ... Very annoying when trying to debug something.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue. I found here a solution which works for me : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517671#c58

For me it was sufficient to put

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

into ~/.profile.

Hope this will help some of you also.

Comment: thanks... could you repost your answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150005/getting-error-when-opening-eclipse-market      I will mark your answer as correct answer

Comment: thanks a lot. that helps me also. Works in Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 3):

For me, this causes by ATI Desktop Manager.

After killing "HydraDM.exe" process, the problem was gone.
When I re-run it again, the problem return.

So if you're using ATI Graphic Card, try to open Task Manager, locate "HydraDM.exe" (or 64 bit version) then kill it.

Comment: what is `HydraDM.exe`? I cannot find any!

Comment: HydraDM.exe is Desktop Manager for ATI Graphic Card.

Answer (score 3):

If you use DisplayFusion:

1. Open Display Fusion settings page
2. Click compatibility tab
3. Add Eclipse or STS.exe application
4. Check "Disable TitleBar Buttons (this application only), "Disable Application Hooks (this application only)", and "Use Process file icon on DisplayFusion taskbar, not window icon"

Reference: [Display Fusion FIX](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983#c67)

Answer (score 3):

Wow, what a variety of causes of these error messages! I'll throw one more out:

In my case, Eclipse 4.17 on Ubuntu 16.04LTS was showing these messages for multiple operations. It turns out that 16.04LTS has GTK 3.18, but Eclipse 4.17 requires GTK 3.20. Updating GTK (https://askubuntu.com/questions/933010/how-to-upgrade-gtk-3-18-to-3-20-on-ubuntu-16-04) made the error messages go away.

Answer (score 2):

I found now 2 ways to work with eclipse without getting “SWTError: No more handles” on my Dell ProBook 6550b Windows 7 64 bit but none of them is really satisfying: I can start windows in “secure mode” or I can downgrade to “eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64”. I will now try to kill one process after the other until kepler starts working respective until I arrive in secure mode.

*... and then a few hours later ...*

Finally (for now) I could solve the issue (at least on my laptop: Dell ProBook 6550b Windows 7 64). I “just” had to kill the processes: “DPAgent.exe*32” (DigitalPersona Local Agent) & “DPAgent.exe” (DigitalPersona 64-bit Helper Process) which were luckily running under my user (and not SYSTEM which might have made it impossible to kill depending on your rights). Nevertheless I don't understand how these processes can interfere with SWT handles in eclipse ....

More information on this issue can as well be found here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fresh Windows 7, **force a Windows Update**. That will make the problem go away. It's a shot in the dark, but solved my problem.
I struggled with it for a day until I realized that newer eclipse releases give the above error with older .net Framework: everything went fine until a driver installed .net 4.0, and from that point Eclipse editor gave the unhandled event loop exception.

Comment: Can confirm that the windows update does fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

I have a nvidia GPU, and if nView is enabled it happens all the time. 
Try to disable it.

It seems that eclipse is not very compatible with softwares that override system window management on multi screen.

Hint how to disable nView: http://nviewdesktopmanager.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-disable-nview-desktop-manager.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally figured out, that it was the Logitech SetPoint Software.

Deinstalled it - and the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after installing HP ProtectTools on HP Probook 6470b, because of included Password Manager.

To disable it run "HP ProtectTools Administrative Console", go to "Applications->Settings", open "Applications" tab and uncheck "Status" checkbox.

After PC restart problem should be solved, but you can't use Password Manager anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

Happens with *Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)* and [*Multimon TaskBar 2.1*](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) on a dual monitor setup, too. It disappears if MM TaskBar is un-loaded.

**UPDATE**

Still the same with *Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2).*

Answer (score 0):

Well, somewhat answering my own question here.
I am still unaware of what causes the issue, but I have found an alternative.

Since the Juno release of Eclipse is relatively recent, the bug itself might have something to do with my system's configuration.

I instead downloaded the latest version of its predecessor, [Eclipse Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2).
Now I am able to use Eclipse just fine.

As I do not require any of the new features of Juno, the Indigo release will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

"unhandled event loop exception .. no more handles" error (in my case) was caused by the driver of my mouse ! closing my mouse driver solved the problem. It has nothing to do with Eclipse versions, I tried almost all versions after Helios(in both 64bit/32bit) and all of them have the same problem, I also tried to add Eclipse/JRE variable path within advanced windows settings "environment variables". To help you to resolve this error try to close up unused applications and drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It is caused by a screen capture software hypersnap7. So I think the hotkey conflict is the reason. Reboot computer, don't start other software, start Android Development Tools and watch which software triger the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I am running dual monitors and have had this issue with both Kepler and STS 3.4.0.  Killing the HydraDM.exe process worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The 'bug' is discussed here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983. A lot of discussion around 'multiple monitor' set-ups. I experienced the problem today(click in Eclipse (off-the-shelf ADT v22.3.0-887826) Package Explorer then click in java editor, and the "no more handles" error appears). It makes Eclipse unuseable.

Got me thinking that it is a monitor/graphics card problem on my win7 64bit PC, rather than a problem with Eclipse. I re-installed the graphics card (nVidia GTX480) and updated the drivers. Noticed multiple error dialog boxes(samsung monitor not found) relating to my monitor(in fact a single BX2440 monitor set-up) as i closed the system down for reboot. So, on re-boot I upgraded the monitor driver. Then booted again, and the problem has gone(at least for now).

BTW, I don't have Win 7 SP1 installed, so i don't think the 'full Windows update' solution discussed elsewhere on SO necessarily works for everyone.

Comment: I had the exact same problem again today. I re-installed the GTX480 drivers, clicked through a windows dialog box "samsung monitor not found", then moved my mouse from Eclipse package explorer panel to java editor panel, and the 'no more handles' error had gone. Will probably re-occur again, but at least I have a fix for now.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was happening on a fresh Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) install and when trying to add a Mercurial repository, I resolved after downgrading from Java 8 to Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem.

OS : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I'm using gnome, I switched from Gnome environment to Gnome Classic environment while logging in and it fixed the issue.

(You can also try other environments like unity - In my case this bug did not appear in Unity or Ubuntu, it only appeared in Gnome )

Answer (score 0):

I work with Liferay dxp-7.2 ga1 in eclipse 2021-12.
I had this same problem, but i solved it changing JVM in the installation menu to java 14, also in Eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 0):

It's a general error, that can be caused by other things (In the error log, look at the preceding error), but I found my culprit: **Theme plugin**.

To be more specific: **Darkest Dark Theme** and **DevStyle** plugin the theme comes with. In my case I could also see 1 UI element that wasn't styled correctly, but I didn't think much of it until diagnosing the issue.

I wouldn't post this as an answer, but in my ~2 weeks of troubleshooting and googling I found older cases that could also be caused by that specific theme.

Comment: What shocks me is that this error still happens with Eclipse after almost 11 years since I wrote this question. I haven't used Eclipse in at least 6 years, and having used other IDEs, I'm shocked anyone still even bothers with Eclipse. Then again, I'm sure it has gotten better over time, too. In all cases, glad you could find a workaround.

Comment: It's a general exception, much like division by 0. Various circumstances (including user error) can lead to cause general exceptions. In my case the exception isn't even caused by eclipse, but rather a plugin that clearly has a bug/compatibility issue.