# Eclipse Unhandled event loop exception No more handles in windows 7

Tags: eclipse, windows-7-x64, handles

I'm facing this error in Eclipse All the time. It occurs every couple of minutes in random cases. I'm using windows 7 64 bit with latest jdk 7 and latest Firefox ( I have seen in many such cases in linux about mozilla ).

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

I have also setup in eclipse.ini

-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

in order to increase memory and set mozilla but still nothing.

Note that it also happens in different instances I have of eclipse ( and in brand new downloaded clean eclipse ) and also in ADT ( Android Tools Eclipse ) .

I can't find a resolution to this and it is getting very annoying.

Any suggestions???

---

Full Error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:112)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:327)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:265)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$15(WorkbenchPage.java:243)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:172)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:193)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:191)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:596)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:549)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:105)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:61)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1447)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2328)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4572)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3129)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3753)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product  org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Windows7 x64 with both Juno & Kepler. Eclispe is totally unusable. Did you find something?

Comment: I downloaded Kepler and set the following lines in eclipse.ini but it didn't solve the problem. It only made the error appear less frequently. If you find some solution please help.

Comment: -Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
-XX:NewSize=16m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=400m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=20m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

Comment: -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+AggressiveOpts #Doesnt work with Android see Google Code Android issue 9883
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this problem has been resolved by updating windows 7 to the latest Windows Update. The last two days I haven't faced this problem again. I hope it does not appear in the future.

Comment: I also solved the problem by updating windows 7 to latest updates.

Comment: I had the same problem: installed a fresh windows, and when installed half of the drivers, Eclipse stopped working. I narrowed it down to a driver installing the .net framework 4.0, but couldn't fix the problem.
However the Windows Update did the trick, everything is fine now.