# Eclipse Unhandled event loop exception with SWTerror

Tags: eclipse

[image]

My os is win7 64bit

I installed jdk for 64bit

after that, set the path and extracted eclipse and excute.

I've done nothing but i have a weird error popup like

```
Unhandled event loop exception


org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$15(WorkbenchPage.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4655)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

This isn't my first installing, i've installed java and ide, bunch of times, but i never had this kinda strange popup before :(

Comment: I found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles , but doesn't have a solution in here too :(

Comment: Well.....instead of 4.x version(juno or kepler), if i use 3.x version(indigo) no more errors, so i'm using indigo for now :(

Comment: Looks like Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983

Comment: Do you use DisplayFusion?