# Eclipse Unhandled event loop exception, no more handles Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, debugging, exception, handle, event-loop

My Eclipse is used to develop Android Apps. It worked fine until one day, an Unhandled event loop exception is prompt. The log is shown below.

To trigger the error prompt, just unfocus the text editor in eclipse and focus it again, then the prompt is triggered, For example, click on the Package Explorer (Red circle) and click on the code (Green circle) in Main.java in Eclipse. (.xml are the same).

But, if I unfocus the code by clicking Package Explorer (Red circle) then click on the title of the code (Blue circle) and then click on the code (Green circle), the error will not be prompted.

P.S. the Android app can be compiled and works fine on the device by using Eclipse. But the error prompt is very annoying.

I have tried:

1. Download the new ADT (Eclipse) from Android Developer and unzip it, not working, still no more handles.
2. Download Eclipse Standard 4.3.1 and unzip it, not working.
3. Restart my computer, Restart Eclipse. Not working.
4. Create a new account of Windows 7 and use the new account to open the same eclipse (throw error in the old account) with the same workspace, It works. No exception is thrown.
5. I tried to replace the C:\oldUser.android with C:\oldUser.android, the old user still throws an exception.
6. Change the default editors in Preferences > General > Editors > File Association > *.xml and Android Manifest, not working.
7. Reset Perspective in Eclipse, not working.
8. Change workspace and use new workspace, not working.

I want to use the old user account to open Eclipse properly.

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$15(WorkbenchPage.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2328)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4572)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3129)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3753)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Session Data:

Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
```

Comment: Similar issue. Check this link 


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles

Answer (score 4):

-----   Display Fusion FIX   -----

1. Open Display Fusion settings page
2. Click compatibility tab
3. Add "Eclipse.exe"
4. Check "Disable TitleBar Buttons (this application only), "Disable Application Hooks (this application only)", and "Use Process file icon on DisplayFusion taskbar, not window icon"

This fix seemed to work for me, the most likely cause for the fix is the "Disable Application Hooks (this application only)", but the 3 worked for me so I have no need to test it further

Answer (score 2):

This is an Eclipse bug, described here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable nView Desktop Manager.
right click on desktop -> "nView Desktop Manager" -> press "Disable" button

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here! :( It seems someone resolved this issue installing all windows updates.
A workaround is use another editor for example (it worked for me): http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201309271200/4.3/
I found this information on stackeroverflow: [Eclipse Bug: Unhandled event loop exception No more handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles)

Update: I installed all windows update and now eclipse Works fine with the default java editor and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I deinstalled Logitech SetPoint Software
This solved this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

This bug has bothered me for quite a while.

I have a nvidia GPU, and if nView is enabled it happens all the time. Try to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I just closed the perspective i was working in (and a few others), closed Eclipse, then restarted Eclipse and that solved the problem (i could open all the perspectives i needed after that)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Eclipse team should fix it up. but It takes time.

Just do system rollback if it occurs after some program installed. A