# unable to open STS aft regular intervals

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

I am working on spring tool suite.I am unable to start STS aft regular intervals say in an interval of 0ne week.STS is not getting opened.can anyone please help me to resolve this?

The log file looks like this..
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles

Comment: Seems like something with Eclipse text Editor. refer,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles.

Answer (score 0):

No more handles is the issue I've seen on Win platform sometimes. SWT uses native platform widgets and hence every widget created with SWT has an OS/Platform resource backing the widget. On Windows this backend resource is called GDI handle or GDI+ handle. If these resources aren't disposed correctly by Eclipse or any other app on your platform you'll eventually get "no more handles" error.
Fixing this such that you could start STS would be to restart the machine i guess.
You can also try increasing the number of handles in Windows. (There is plenty of posts about that. Here is one: http://weblogs.asp.net/mikedopp/increasing-user-handle-and-gdi-handle-limits)
The real issue however must be an application that doesn't dispose GDI resources. For Eclipse application every SWT widget must be disposed at the end.

Comment: And it might be a resource leak in the application (STS or Eclipse in this case). If you have a few instructions how to reproduce that (for example including the parts of Eclipse/STS that you are using, installed third-party plugins, etc.). It is always a bit hard to reproduce and fix these leaks, but we can give it a try. You can report this issue at: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled sts..thats the only way i could get