# Unhandled event loop exception, No more handles

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been trying to set up Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 (64-bit). When I start up and load my workspace I'm greeted with a lovely Problem Occured message saying Unhandled event loop exception. No more handles. It then prompts me asking if I want to close eclipse saying  an SWT error has occurred. I have no calls to SWT in my code as I'm just doing a simple recursion assignment. In fact, even if I start a brand new class with no code in it, clicking into the code to edit it triggers the error. I've also tried updating to Eclipse Luna, uninstalling and reinstalling Eclipse Kepler, and making the default editor WindowBuilder as suggested at [Eclipse Bug: Unhandled event loop exception No more handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles) but nothing has worked. Below is my exception stack trace

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$17(WorkbenchPage.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4654)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: I have the following on my computer: eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64, it is kepler 64 bit on windows 7, but I have a different java, i got 7 maybe you should go back to java 7. Also I keep hearing Luna is buggy

Comment: Java 7 has the same issue, I just tried that. I think its an OS issue

Comment: Is it Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers download?

Comment: No it just said Eclipse for Java developers

Comment: Why don't you give Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers a try instead with Java 7 and see what happens

Comment: It seems to be an evergreen: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to update Windows 7