# Eclipse Unhandled event loop exception no more handles - Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: eclipse, exception

I have tried searching but cannot find my answer. I would appreciate any help.

I get this error when editing 2+ windows in Eclipse.Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1). eg., Open 2 class windows.

When clicking one panel to make `class A` active. If I click `Class B` to make `Class A` the active panel I get the same error.

Workaround is to close so I only have one panel showing for editing my class.

Unhandled event loop exception

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$17(WorkbenchPage.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4654)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

I also get:

```
Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used     to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories:     'C:\Users\Chris'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

But I have tried to install Git within Eclipse to no avail.

Thank you in advance,
Chris

Comment: It's hard to help without the source code. The problem indicates that you are not disposing some resources properly, for example Colors.

Comment: Possibly Eclipse bug [402983](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983). See the (long) discussion in the bug report for various possible resolutions.

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much greg.  I had to disable DisplayFusion (multi monitor app)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Fedora 25 / Eclipse Neon.3. After lot of searching I found [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497705#c3). Workaround for any Fedora/Linux users if they find same issue is to run following commands before starting Eclipse:

```
export SWT_WEBKIT2=1
export SWT_GTK3=0
./eclipse
```

Comment: That soled problem in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case what solved the problem, was Windows update.

Comment: Do you have an idea as to which update fixed the issue. The Eclipse site also says this as not an eclipse issue.
I am getting this when I try to open an existing BIRT report
I am using Luna 64 bit with Java 8 64 bit on Windows 7 Prof 64 bit

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I had this problem on a freshly installed Window 7 Pro 64bit Service Pack 1, Java 8 64bit and Eclipse Luna 64bit. When I launched the Windows update I had more than 130 updates to install. So, now would be a lot of time wasting to manually install one update at a time to narrow down which one really fixes the problem. And I'm not even sure if only one update will fix it, it could be a combination of them ...

Comment: No issue, I came down to Kepler and everything is fine; I will upgrade to luna some other time

Answer (score 0):

For me it was fixed by turning off "nVidia Desktop Manager".

Other people fixed the problem by turning off other desktop manager apps like "DisplayFussion".

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the reason is having some resources (controls, images, fonts...) not disposed.

But e.g. for creating controls, exception is being thrown, when OS.CreateWindowEx() returns 0 (you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx for more details)

(This relates to Windows impl of SWT only of course)

1. You can use free Sysinternal Process Explorer to check whether you've actually taken too much handles (In Process Explorer wnd, choose View>Select Columns... > Process Memory tab > check "USER Objects")
2. Possible reason can be e.g. passing invalid parent into control's constructor

Hope this helps