# Eclipse shows empty error message with Java 9

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

I have installed the Java 9 plugin. My project hasn't changed, but when I try to run, I get this:[image: Empty error dialog]

If you need anything else, feel free to comment that you don't have enough info.

My `.log` file: https://pastebin.com/SQXZVcQk

Comment: Which plugin? From where? Did the project work before? Can you reproduce the issue with a small mini project (e.g. only one class with a main)? Can you provide the content of Eclipse error log file? Does the project work again if removing the plugin? At the current state it is **not enough information** to help you (apart from users that faced the exact same issue already).

Comment: The official java 9 plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace

Comment: It works in Java 8

Comment: What error log?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: Do you have the URL for that plugin?

Comment: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen

Comment: @RayWu - How do you configure the Libraries of the project? Jdk to be used, library.path etc?

Comment: I use the 'Build Path' in eclipse

Comment: What version of Eclipse?

Comment: The tag says Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: I get this, too.    It's clearly a horrible UI bug in Eclipse.  At the least, it should manage to gasp out what it is objecting to.     Copying the source file and renaming it clears the error for a while.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

This is with Eclipse   Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a configuration issue as per my understanding. There are two possible causes/solution to it:

1. From the logs:

   > ```
   > Root exception:
   > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   >     at com.jniwrapper.util.ProcessorInfo.b(SourceFile:95)
   > Caused by: com.jniwrapper.LibraryNotFoundException: Cannot find JNIWrapper native library (jniwrap64.dll) in java.library.path:
   > ```

   Eclipse is not able to configure the `java.library.path` properly, in which case you can try setting the VM argument using the following on the command line:

   ```
   -Djava.library.path="${workspace_loc:project}\lib;${env_var:PATH}"
   ```

   Check out [How to add native library to "java.library.path" with Eclipse launch (instead of overriding it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of) for further details and platform specific solutions.

   `&&` make sure you include the path to jdk-9 early access build that should ideally be a must for the plugin used based out of Java9.
2. Also, the log reads

   > ```
   > !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-08-27 09:22:31.358
   > !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
   > !STACK 0
   > java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
   >     at es.org.chemi.games.snake.ui.GameField.createGameField(GameField.java:217)
   >     at es.org.chemi.games.snake.ui.GameField$1.controlResized(GameField.java:99)
   >     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:236)
   >     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
   >     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
   >     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
   > ```

   For the pertaining code, you might want to look into the implementation of 
   `createGameField at GameField.java:217`. If this wasn't specifically occurring on previous java version for you then solving (1) should get rid of this or else you might want to give the solutions at [Eclipse Bug: Unhandled event loop exception No more handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles) a try.

Answer (score -2):

On receiving the same error in eclipse I fixed it by selecting this option instead of the default (highlighted by the red arrow in the snapshot)

[image: Use a project specific JRE is selected]