# Java Program not running; error box is blank?

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

sorry if this question was repeated earlier, but I couldnt seem to find the answer. I have a code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PracticeProblems {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        x= input.nextInt();
        if(x%2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x%2==0); 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(x%2==0);
        }


    }

}
```

Now I am not too worried if the code actually works or not (because this same problem has occurred when the code was perfectly functional) I am just as confused why it doesnt run.
[image: ERROR BOX]

Comment: look closely at the error msg in the img. in __Java__ class name should be same as filename.java i.e PracticeProblem == ComputeArea

Comment: @roottraveller The filename is already the same as the class name. What that red message tells us is something different: OP runs an outdated  run configuration.

Comment: Did you notice the error message in the console? It is very clear about what is wrong. Concerning the empty error box, you should file an issue in the Eclipse bug tracker: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse shows empty error message with Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907867/eclipse-shows-empty-error-message-with-java-9)

Answer (score 1):

Try running by right clicking on **PracticeProblems.java**, and choosing "Run As Application".  It looks like it is trying to run **ComputeArea**, and can't find that class.

Comment: i was trying to run all of my programs to see if any run but the same error message appears

Comment: Then I would suspect eclipse is in a bad state.  You can try closing your project and re-opening it, or restarting eclipse.  If that doesn't work, create a new workspace and recreate the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problems too.

1. Eclipse > Projects > Clean
2. if its not working try to copy the class. Delete the Project and recreate it

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problems many times.

To solve this problem save the program, close Eclipse, reopen it and run the program without any loss of the program.

It works fine.