# Red X and nothing more in error window

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a student who is using Eclipse to run java code. She creates a project, loads a java source code file into it. There are no errors being flagged. When she tries to run it, an window pops up with nothing but a red X, and a title of "Error". I watched her do it (remotely, she is an online student). Then, she creates a copy of the code file, exits Eclipse, starts Eclipse, deletes the copy and the original now works. I have no idea what to tell her. This happens with each code file she tries, and in every project she creates. Any ideas?

Update: I now have two students who are getting the error. One is using a MAC, the other Windows Here is a screen capture:
[Error Mesage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcDQb.png)

Comment: Find out by which process the error window is created (e. g. on Windows via the Task Manager). A Google image search with the name of the executable file may help to identify the cause. If that doesn't help, add more information and a screenshot to your question.

Comment: It is created by Eclipse

Comment: How do you know that? In Eclipse, which plug-ins are installed?

Comment: The dialog box has an Eclipse icon on the title bar.

Comment: I have no idea about plug-ins. She claims to have followed my instructions on the install, which is just install Java JDK and the standard Eclipse download. I have no reason to suspect she has not done that. Perhaps a re-install?

Comment: This sounds similar (empty error dialog caused by [this plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-games)): https://stackoverflow.com/q/45907867/6505250

Comment: My suggestion for ensuring your students a fully operative, working environment is that you could create and configure a fulll Eclipse within a Virtual Machine (like VirtualBox), upload the image file, and tell them to download it into their VMs.