# Getting Error when opening Eclipse Market

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tools-4

Getting Error when opening Eclipse Marketplace or install new software.

> Unhandled event loop exception during blocked modal context. No more
>   handles

[image]

[image]

**Eclipse Spring Tool Suite Version**

Spring Tool Suite 4

Version: 4.4.2.RELEASE

Build Id: 201911201053

**Here is my Java version**

java version "1.8.0_201"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

**My OS**

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19 Tara
Release:    19
Codename:   tara

Thank you in advance!

Comment: see this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537495

Comment: the link doesn't help

Comment: the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles/22313170

Comment: @YusufIbrahim You have linked a question more than 6 years old, not an answer. Please avoid asking an existing question again (vote up the answer that solved your problem and delete your question).

Comment: not quite the same, my issue is from the latest 4.4.2.RELEASE of STS, I will keep it here since it's take so long for me to get the answer and I am sure it will still help somebody out there

Comment: great bro @YusufIbrahim it's really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. I found here a solution which works for me : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517671#c58

For me it was sufficient to put

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

into ~/.profile.

Hope this will help some of you also.

[Eclipse Bug: Unhandled event loop exception No more handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles/22313170) <- Heiko's answers